# React number format for thousands comma, toLocaleString not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to format numbers coming from a response object to have a comma in the thousands place.

I have attempted using .toLocaleString but it just removes all zeroes? I.e. in my example below, it turns 'test' into 2 when it is set to 2000.0 or 2000.

What is happening here and how can I get my values to display with commas?

```
    var test = 2000.0;

    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        cards[0].value = test.toLocaleString('en') || 100;
        cards[1].value = data['xxx'] || 100;
        cards[2].value = data['xxx'] || 100;
        cards[3].value = data['xxx'] || 100;
        cards[4].value = data['xxx'] || 100;
        cards[5].value = data['xxx'] || 100;

        this.setState({ xxx: cards });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.toString()));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `test` must be `2` before `toLocaleString` because otherwise it'd be converted to `"2,000"` and not `"2"` as you mention.

Proof:

```
var test = 2000.0;
console.log(test.toLocaleString('en'));

// prints: 2,000
```

So, you'll need to run your code with a debugger, or simply add a `console.log(test);` exactly before the `toLocaleString` line to confirm.

Comment: I checked to make sure 'test' was not being accessed anywhere else and even tried a different variable name. I also tried moving it to the line immediately before it is modified and it still has the same issue. Running .toLocaleString() on that variable results in 2000 becoming 2.

Comment: What do you get if you place `console.log((2000.0).toLocaleString('en'))` anywhere inside your react application?